# Using ctypes to make a GUI text popup in python

Tags: python, windows

I've been making Python programs recently and just worked out how to use cTypes to make a text gui and I couldn't find any way to be able to tell what button the user presses. So like if the person presses cancel the program closes and if they say ok the program goes through.

This is my code:

```
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox(None, 'text', 'title', 0)
```

Thank you so much if you can help

Comment: How about reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox)?

Answer (score 0):

The 4th argument passed to `MessageBoxW` determines the buttons shown in the message box. The return value of the call give you the ID of the pressed button. Consider the simple test:

```
import ctypes
MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
res = MessageBox(None, 'text', 'title', 1)
print(res)
```

Try running it with clicking the two different buttons, and see that you get different results.

For the full usage instructions, though, you really should read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox)

Answer (score 0):

This will 100% work if not please comment

```
import ctypes  
def closeProgram():
    pass

messageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
res = messageBox(0,'Your title', 'Your text',1)

if res ==1:
    #only if user press Ok
    closeProgram()
```